# Possibilities of crawling pinterest and quora like sites

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, pinterest

I have been trying to scrape some websites (AJAX based) for my research . I have a condition that i should  scrape the contents without logging into an account of respective website.

**DOUBT**

I can see a huge difference in page source code with and without logging in .I know it is because of AJAX but  I need to scrape one of these sites preferably pinterest by somehow.I am new to Web scraping so let me know if you guys have any idea on how to go about this

**Additional Condition** 
No selenium solutions or web driver based solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to follow this path:

1. If there is an API, use the API. You save the remote resources as well as yours as you don't need to render anything. You might find if website uses an API in e.g. Developer Tools of your browser (Network tab, XHR).
2. Use Splash as a rendering service. It has seamless integration with Scrapy using `scrapy-splash` package and from my experience works more reliably than Selenium.

Comment: these API are built in different manner. I checked after logging into one of the account. These API requires lot of header information includes cookies etc. I want to scrape things like public page scapping .